# How to test REST API + Client-side MVC apps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

When you have a RESTful server which only responds with JSON by fetching some information from the database, and then you have a client-side application, such as Backbone, Ember or Angular, from which side do you test an application?

Do I need two tests - one set for back-end testing and another set for front-end testing?

The reason I ask is testing REST API by itself is kind of difficult. Consider this code example (using Mocha, Supertest, Express):

```
var request = require('supertest');
var should = require('chai').should();
var app  = require('../app');

describe('GET /api/v1/people/:id', function() {
  it('should respond with a single person instance', function(done) {
    request(app)
      .get('/api/v1/people/:id')
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        var json = res.body;
        json.should.have.property('name');
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Notice that `:id` in the url? That's an ObjectId of a specific person. How do I know what to pass there? I haven't even looked into the database at this point. Does that I mean I need to import `Person` model, connect to database and do queries from within the tests? Maybe I should just move my entire app.js into tests? (sarcasm :P). That's a lot of coupling. Dependency on mongoose alone means I need to have MongoDB running locally in order to run this test. I looked into sinon.js, but I am not sure if it's applicable here. There weren't many examples on how to stub mongoose.

**I am just curious how do people test these kinds of applications?**

Comment: IMHO testing a REST API is easy compared to most other types of test. This is the minimum test you should have. In most cases the API test is some kind of "integration test". Write a setup-script for your database and run the API tests against this well-known database state. I wouldn't stub/mock the database. Sometimes it's easier to test a "whole story" than just single, isolated steps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [mongoose-model-stub](https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-model-stub) in your server-side test? It will free you from having to remember or hardcode database info for your tests.

As for testing the client side, your "webapp" is basically two apps: a server API and a client-side frontend. You want tests for both ideally. You already know how to test your server. On the client you would test your methods using stubbed out "responses" (basically fake json strings that look like what your web service spits out) from your API. These don't have to be live urls; rather it's probably best if they're just static files that you can edit as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would use nock..https://github.com/pgte/nock

What you want to test is the code you have written for your route.
So what you do is, create a response that will be sent when the end point is hit.

Basically its a fake server.. 
Something like this..

Your actual method..

```
request({
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://sampleserver.com/account"
    }, function(err, res, data){
      if (err) {
        done(err);
      } else {
        return done(null,data);
      }
    });
```

Then..

```
var nockObj = nock("http://sampleserver.com")
                        .get("/account")
                        .reply(200,mockData.arrayOfObjects);
  //your assertions here..
```

This way you don't alter the functionality of your code.. Its like saying.. instead of hitting the live server..hit this fake server and get mock data. All you have to do is make sure your mock data is in sync with the expected data..